# Lifetime of a string literal returned by a function

Tags: c++, c, lifetime, string-literals

Consider this code:

```
const char* someFun() {
    // ... some stuff
    return "Some text!!"
}

int main()
{
   { // Block: A
      const char* retStr = someFun();
      // use retStr
   }
}
```

In the function `someFun()`, where is `"Some text!!"` stored (I think it may be in some static area of ROM) and what is its <del>scope</del> lifetime?

Will the memory pointed by `retStr` be occupied throughout the program or be released once the block A exits?

Comment: you may also take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267114/scope-of-string-literals

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The C++ Standard does not say where string literals should be stored. It does however guarantee that their lifetime is the lifetime of the program. Your code is therefore valid.

Comment: Could you reference the (draft) standard?

Comment: Not official, but this may help - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#:~:text=fwide-exec-charset.-,String%20literals%20have%20static%20storage%20duration,String,-literals%20can%20be

Answer (score 34):

The `"Some text!!"` does not have a *scope*. *Scope* is a property of a *named* entity. More precisely, it is a property of the name itself. `"Some text!!"` is a *nameless* object - a string literal. It has no name, and therefore any discussions about its "scope" make no sense whatsoever. It has no scope.

What you seem to be asking about is not *scope*. It is *lifetime* or *storage duration* of `"Some text!!"`. String literals in C/C++ have *static storage duration*, meaning that they live "forever", i.e. as long as the program runs. So, the memory occupied by `"Some text!!"` is never released.

Just keep in mind (as a side note) that string literals are non-modifyable objects. It is illegal to write into that memory.

Comment: congratulate for reaching 300k reputation :)

Answer (score 5):

String will be stored statically in special (usually read-only on modern OS) section of the program binary. Its memory is not allocated (individually for the string, only for total section while loading it to memory) and will not be deallocated.

Comment: That's no necessarily true. What if the binary format you're linking to doesn't support the notion of "read-only sections"? (e.g. most basic COM files)

Comment: mamonts doesn't have read only sections too. They have only historic interest.

Comment: even in com file there will be some part (section of file), or several, for storing constants. They will be not marked as read only in segments or in page descriptors, but the idea will be the same.

Comment: That was just an extreme example where it's **not possible** to put the string in a "read only section" (since there are no sections). The point is that this being impossible the standard doesn't impose such a requirement, and therefore a complying compiler/linker might not do it, **even when it is possible**.

Comment: Regarding COM files you are absolutely wrong: COM files are **real-mode** "memory snapshots", and even that memory area in which **logically** the linker put all the constants isn't read-only in any way. **Real-mode** doesn't have any memory protection features of that sort.

Comment: Ok, edited the answer. Even gcc can put string consts to write-enabled memory.

Comment: @conio, form wiki (sorry): 
>" COM file can either be very simple, using a single segment, or arbitrarily complex, providing its own memory management system"

It will loaded as snapshot, but it can even change the mode to protected.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Windows was also implemented at a time in a COM file: `win.com`, but a COM file **in itself** has no notion of memory protection. **AFTER** the binary is loaded and running its code can do anything, but the binary format itself has no notion of memory protection. You see, the **code** inside the file can cause a transition to protected mode, but a COM file **in itself** doesn't do that. Your argument is analogous to saying that since I can board an airplane with a skateboard it means that skateboards can fly...

Comment: @conio, elf itself does not have memory protection too (it is a byte stream). Memory protection is applyed by elf loader either in OS or in dynamic loader (and file can be loaded from disk to memory/pagecache before it will be mapped with right protection).   C program compiled in COM will be run AFTER crt. And crt MAY add some protection.   COM files can contain info for linker, so code from COM will be run only after loading it by (external to this COM) linker.

Comment: Actually, COM files don't contain information for the linker-loader. They are plain memory snapshots. That's written in the wikipedia article you quoted earlier: *It is very simple; it has no header, and contains no metadata, only code and data.*

EXE files on the other hand contain sections that can be marked as read-only, and the Windows loader (which runs in protected mode and is aware of its capabilities) marks the pages corresponding to the EXE section appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I posted answer on similar question so I will use that example here too.

Short answer is string literal "message2" will exist in memory
as long as process, but in .*rodata* section (assuming we talk about ELF file).

We return pointer to string constant, but as we will latter see, there is not separate memory defined anywhere which stores this `const char *` pointer
and there is no need to, as address of string is calculated in code and returned using register $**rax** every time function is called.

But lets take a look in the code what happens with **gdb**

[image]

We put breakpoint in our function returning a pointer to constant string, and we see assembly code and process map:

[image]

Code gets this string in following instruction:

```
0x000055555555514a <+8>:    lea    0xeb3(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555556004
```

What this instruction does it calculates address of "message2".
We see here what PIC (position independent code) means.

Address of "message2" string is not hardcoded as absolute,
but is calculated as relative, as hardcoded offset 0xeb3 of next instruction address (0x555555555151 + 0xeb3) and put in register **rax**.

Purpose of relative addressing (current address +/- offset)
means process will always get the right address of "message2",
no matter where in memory it is loaded.

So here we see that `const char *` that you asked actually doesn't exist in memory, because address is calculated "on the fly" and returned using $rax:

We have address in $rax:

```
(gdb) i r $rax
rax   0x555555556004      93824992239620
```

And it holds address of "message2":

```
(gdb) x/s 0x555555556004
0x555555556004: "message2"
```

Now lets see where address **0x555555556004** in process address map
is:

```
0x555555556000     0x555555557000     0x1000     0x2000  r--p   /home/drazen/proba/main
```

So this section is not executable and not writable, just readable and private (r--p) which makes sense as this is not shared library.

When we check with readelf it shows that it is in the .rodata section of ELF file:

```
drazen@HP-ProBook-640G1:~/proba$ readelf  -x .rodata main

Hex dump of section '.rodata':
0x00002000 01000200 6d657373 61676532 00       ....message2.
```

So answer is that this string will not be hardcoded in code segment *.text* of the ELF file but read only data segment *.rodata*, but yes it will exist as long process exists in memory.

And just to add small detail, this constant string will be returned to main() function by reference of course (address), but not on the stack but in register **rax**:

```
(gdb) i r
rax   0x555555556004      93824992239620
rbx   0x0
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -4):

> Will the memory pointed by retStr be occupied throughout the program or be released once the block A exits?

**Edit:**

It will be **not** released, but `retStr` will not be available. (block scope)

```
const char *ptr;
{   
   const char* retStr = "Scope";
   ptr = retStr;
}   

printf("%s\n", ptr); //prints "Scope"

//printf("%s\n", retStr); //will throw error "retStr undeclared"
```

Comment: it will Not be released only the symbol retStr wouldn't be available

Comment: Incorrect.  The memory that retStr points to after the execution is static memory.  It is allocated when the application starts and is only released (effectively) when the application terminates.

Comment: @all: my mistake, i was thinking about `retStr`. Will change the answer.