# Why assign string to pointer is safe in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class:
.h

```
class test {
public:
    int Length;
    char* Name;
    int* ARR;
    test(int l, char* n, int* a);
    test();
};
```

.cpp

```
test::test(int l, char* n, int* a){
    Length=l;
    Name=n;
    ARR=a;
}
```

And main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
void InAFunc(test *kio) {
    int foo[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    *kio = test(7, "Hello!", foo);
}
int main() {
    test mmk;
    InAFunc(&mmk);
    std::cout << mmk.Name << mmk.ARR[1];
}
```

As I know, I may got an exception on ARR, because variable foo has been release at the end of function InAFunc. I need to do new or malloc to Arr to avoid it.
My question is why "Hello!" is safe? I code a lot like this in the past but never wrong. Why leaving a string in constructor without new or malloc is OK?
Variable Name in this class is a pointer.

Comment: the string "Hello" is a string literal which exists throughout the duration of the program. Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579874/lifetime-of-a-string-literal-returned-by-a-function

Comment: Read about program segments, especially data segment, you will understand where this "Hello!" exist. btw there is so many errors in this small example

Comment: `kio=test(7,"Hello!",foo)` -- here, `kio` is a pointer. This will not compile, which tells me that the shown code is not the actual code. As such, any answers to this question will be meaningless, since they will not be based on real code you're working with.

Comment: Please post code that actually compiles and exhibit's the behavior you are describing. The code you posted has many, many mistakes and will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

The string "Hello" is a `string literal` which exists through out the duration of the program. So you can always point to it without breaking pointers. It wont be destroyed at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has **undefined behavior** (which means a crash is not guaranteed!), but not for the reason you think it does.

`InAFunc()` takes a `test` object *by value*, so a *copy* of the input `test` object is made when `InAFunc()` is called.  Any modifications that `InAFunc()` makes to its `kio` parameter are local to `InAFunc()` and not reflected back to the caller.

The `mmk` variable in `main()` is default-constructed, so presumably `mmk.Name` and `mmk.ARR` are NULL (you didn't show the code for that constructor, though), and `InAFunc()` will not overwrite that.  It is *undefined behavior* to pass a NULL `char*` pointer to `operator<<`, or to index into a NULL `int*` pointer.

You probably wanted `InAFunc()` to output the new `test` object that it creates.  In which case, the `kio` parameter needs to be passed *by reference* instead of *by value*:

```
void InAFunc(test &kio)
```

Now the `mmk` variable in `main()` will receive the values that `InAFunc()` assigns.  `mmk.Name` and `mmk.ARR` will not be NULL anymore.

You would now be assigning a pointer to a **string literal** to `mmk.Name`, and a *string literal* resides in persistent read-only memory for the lifetime of the process, so passing `mmk.Name` to `operator<<` will be well-defined and not crash.

However, `mmk.ARR` will indeed be pointing to an array that is local to `InAFunc()` and will not be valid anymore once `InAFunc()` exits, as you suspected.  So, you would have *undefined behavior* when you try to index into `mmk.ARR` (though the memory that `mmk.ARR` is pointing at will likely still be *allocated*, so the code will likely not crash).

Answer (score 0):

> Why leaving a string in constructor without new or malloc is OK?
>   Why assign string to pointer is safe in constructor?

In C++, everything **are objects**:

- An `int` is an object.
- A string literal is an object.
- A pointer too is an object which can be assigned.

Thus, the pointer `Name` is *pointing to* the location where the *string literal* resides.

Answer (score 0):

oh,i didn't figure out what the problem is.
constant string literal is in an area(read only section) which managed by compiler,
it will be free until the program stops.
[String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go)
.....................................

The type of "hello" is char*(in fact char[6]), rather than a string. char* can be used as string because of the implicit conversion, std::string has a constructor which accepts char* as parameter.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

btw, "kio=test(...)" cannot compile.

Comment: actually it is `const char[6]`  (or 7 in this case since the string is "Hello!"

Comment: 7 due to null char.