# When its safe to use char array from a different class?

Tags: c++

I have two classes, class B comtains a static function "funcEx" which has a pointer as param. funcEx should insert the param data into a map.

Class A uses this funx in order to keep params inside the static map.
What would happen after class A is destroyed.
Will the memory allocation of "param_name" will be released?

```
class A{
B::funcEx("param_name");
}

class B{
static map<const char*, int, cmp_str> *Map1 ;
static Map1 = new std::map<const char *, int, cmp_str>();

static funcEx(const char * param){
Map1.insert(param,8)
}

}
```

Comment: This is not C++

Comment: Would you mind to give us a more complete example (ideally a [mcve]). We need to know how exactly the string literal is stored in `class A`, etc. to give you a correct answer.

Comment: this is not c++ syntax but the question is how c++ reacts in kind of this situation
when it gets "char array" from the function param into a pointer

Comment: You question doesn't make much sense: "a char array which was set on class A" does a poor job as describing _something_. This is why we need an example, and we need a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: You wrote _"the static map"_; I ask **which map**?

Comment: `"param_name"` is a string literal in your example, it will live until the end of the program and a pointer to it may therefore be safely saved in a map. Is that your question? If it is, your pseudo-code doesn't make sense though, as `func` is part of class `B` but called in `A`.

Comment: I reshaped the question hope its better. yes this was my question, thank you very much. I was worried that in some point after class A is destroyed "param_name" will be freed

Comment: Your example still doesn't make much sense. If you want to call `funcEx` in `A`, you must use a qualified name to look it up, e.g. `B::funcEx`. Furthermore the string literal cannot be passed as `char*`, only `const char*`. Also note that my previous comment only holds for string literals, not char arrays. Additionally of course the `map` declaration, access specifiers and an enclosing function for the call in `A` are missing. (and `Class` should be `class`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lifetime of a string literal returned by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579874/lifetime-of-a-string-literal-returned-by-a-function)

Comment: Thanks again. I fixed the example above. yes I used a const char* in the code to point to the string, so it now seems to me that the map will point to the string which be allocated in memory till the end of the program

Comment: What is the reason you don't use `std::string` and just not have to worry about it?

Comment: @15412s _"I fixed the example above"_ Your now edited example is still far from valid c++. Also you still left the question open how the `const char*` is stored within 'class A'.

Comment: @15412s Even if I fix the most basic syntax, your code won't compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d3f908eb5d0d26b

Comment: const char* is not stored in class a, const char* is the type of input from B::funcEx. what would be the difference from using std::string instead of const char* to point to the string?

Comment: If you use `std::string` instead of `const char*` the class will automatically copy the string (literal) and you don't need to worry about lifetime of the original anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said a literal string like "param_name" is immortal.

To try to answer you :

```
#include <map>

class B {
  public:
    static void funcEx(const char * param) {
      map[param] = 8;
    }
  private:
    static std::map<const char *, int> map;
};

std::map<const char *, int> B::map;

class A {
  public:
    A(char c) { member[0] = c; member[1] = 0; }
    void f() { B::funcEx("param_name"); }
    void g() { B::funcEx(member); }
    void h(char * s) { B::funcEx(s); }
  private:
    char member[2];
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   A * x = new A('x');
   {
     A y('y');

     {
       char s[] = "ab";

       x->f(); // nothing change with y->f()
       x->g();
       y.g();
       x->h(s); // x can be y

       // here all the keys/pointers into the map still exist

       delete x;

       // here x is deleted
       // => x->member has an unknown value
       // => "x" used as a key in the map is an invalid pointer, may be it is not anymore the string "x"
     }

     // here 's' does not exist anymore
     // the key "ab" in the map is an invalid pointer, may it is not anymore the string "ab"
   }

   // here 'y' does not exist
   // => y.member has an unknown value
   // => "y" used as a key in the map is an invalid pointer, may be it is not anymore the string "y"

   return 0;
}
```

Because all is static in B that class has no real interest