# std::vector - how to free the memory of char* elements in a vector?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, std

Consider the following C++ codes :

```
using namespace std;
vector<char*> aCharPointerRow;
aCharPointerRow.push_back("String_11");
aCharPointerRow.push_back("String_12");
aCharPointerRow.push_back("String_13");
for (int i=0; i<aCharPointerRow.size(); i++)  {
   cout << aCharPointerRow[i] << ",";
}
aCharPointerRow.clear();
```

After the `aCharPointerRow.clear();` line, the character pointer elements in `aCharPointerRow` should all be removed.

Is there a memory leak in the above C++ code ? Do I need to explicitly free the memory allocated to the char* strings ? If yes, how ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You handle your allocations, then `vector` will handle its own allocations.

Comment: It should be `vector<const char*>`. A `char*` pointer allows modification, but `"String_11"` is a string literal and therefore `const`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Is there a memory leak in the above C++ code?**
There is no memory leak.

Since you never used `new` you do not need to call `delete`. You only need to deallocate dynamicmemory if it was allocated in first place.

Note that ideally, You should be using vector of `std::string`.

```
std::vector<std::string> str;
str.push_back("String_11");
str.push_back("String_12");
str.push_back("String_13");
```

You could use **[std::string.c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)** in case you need to get the underlying character pointer(`char *`), which lot of C api expect as an parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You are pushing in your vector string literals (the strings in `"..."`). These aren't allocated by you. They are given to you by the C++ compiler/runtime and they have a lifetime equal to the lifetime of the app, so you can't/mustn't free them.

See for example [Scope of (string) literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267114/scope-of-string-literals)

Note that everything I told you was based on the fact that you are using string literals. If you need to allocate your strings' memory, then you will have to use some automatic deallocators like `std::unique_ptr` (of C++11) or `boost::unique_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` (of Boost) or better use the `std::string` class as suggested by Als

Comment: Why not simply use `std::string` instead?

Comment: @Als `or better use the std::string class as suggested by Als`

Comment: @Als And in the end I wanted to show to the OP the "richness" of auto-pointers. If he is really interested in C++ he will need them...

Comment: Fair Enough, I don't notice that quot, My bad.

Comment: @xanatos Thanks for your suggestions. I know the existence of smart pointers. I am just new to C++ and want to clarify the concepts of std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

The sample has no leak, since the pointer you give don't refer to dynamic memory.

But is also a bad written code: string literals are constant, but C++ allow to refer them as char* to retain a C library backward compatibility. If you intend to refer to string literals, you should better use `const char*` instead of `char*` (in case of an attempt to modify them you got a compiler error, not a runtime exception)

Another bad thing, here, is that in a more extensive code, you sooner or later lose the control on what are the char* effectively stored in the vector: Are they granted to always be string literals or can they also be some other way allocated dynamic char[] ?? And who is responsible for their allocation / deallocation ?

std::vector says nothing about that, and if you are in the position you cannot give a clean answer to the above questions (each `const char*` referred buffer can be either exist outside the vector existence scope or not), you have probably better to use `std::vector<std::string>`, and treat the strings as "values" (not referenced objects), letting the string class to do the dirty job.

Answer (score 1):

There is no leak. As long as you're not making a copy of those strings, you don't need to explicitly delete or free() them.