# Where is local pointer stored in memory?

Tags: c, pointers

I am beginner in C. I have one program as below:

```
int main()
{
    char* func();
    char *c;
    c = func();
    printf("%s", c);
}

char* func()
{
    char *ptr = "OK";
    return ptr;
}
```

As we all know, `ptr` is a local variable of `func()` and is a pointer. The scope is local.
But when `ptr` is returned to the caller, `main`, it is still valid and when `c` is printed, it prints "OK".

How is this possible? In which memory segment is `ptr` stored; stack, or heap?

Answer (score 9):

This is what's going under the hood when using pointer (Note that pointer is just like what the name implies, something like a finger pointing to something).

Let's break down your codes and understand it bit by bit.
In your main function, you declared a character pointer *c

```
char *c;
```

Then you did this:

```
c = func();
```

which tells the c pointer to point to whatever this func() is pointing to.

Let's look at your function

```
char* func()
{
    char *ptr = "OK";
    return ptr;
}
```

The first line, again, declare a character pointer ptr, and assigned "OK" to that address (Note: pointer just points to some memory address). So now, that address contains the string "OK" (or more precisely, an array of char).

Then you return ptr, which is the address of where "OK" is located at. Note that because ptr is declared in func(), it is a local variable. Hence, once return, it is removed from the **stack** (poof! Gone).

However, because in your main():

```
c = func();
```

The variable c is pointing to the address of where "OK" is stored. Hence, even though the variable ptr no longer exist, the variable c knows where it is, and can still access "OK".

To answer your question:

- ptr is stored at **stack**
- and ptr is pop off from the stack when you exit the func()

Answer (score 4):

Let us forget about stack/heap for a moment. Let's talk C.

The local variable `ptr` doesn't exist outside `func`, so the caller *cannot* and should not *refer* to it.

But [C doesn't do *pass by reference*](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html). Everything is passed by value. `func` returns the *value* stored in `ptr` to its caller. Much like you would return the *value* of an `int` or any other type.

So for your example, `ptr`'s value is the address of a string literal called `"OK"`. And [string literals are valid during the entire scope of the program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267114/274261). So `func` returns the address of a string literal, which is allowed to be dereferenced anywhere in the program.

To be more clear, `func` is equivalent to:

```
const char * func (void)
{
  return "OK";
}
```

This is why everything works out fine.

It is also useful to know that while the following is OK:

```
const char * func (void)
{
  char *ptr = "OK";
  return ptr;
}
```

This is not:

```
const char * func (void)
{
  char ptr[] = "OK";
  return ptr;
}
```

It is not OK because *now* you're returning a pointer to an array which is *local* to `func`.

One more small point. It should be: `const char * func ()`, because `"OK"` is not allowed to be modified.

Answer (score 3):

When you're calling the function, all its local variables and return address pushes onto the stack. So ptr will be on the stack, but "OK"-string in constant data section. When you're returning from `func`, value of `ptr` is assigned to `c` variable, `ptr` is no longer exists (actually, exists), but its value stored in `c`.

Comment: the C standard doesn't use the term "stack"

Comment: I agree with you .. But my doubt is when func returns , scope of ptr ends with func .. How it is still valid ? Thats what i am not able to understand ..

Comment: For example, return value may be stored in eax register when returning from function.

Answer (score 2):

The text `"OK"` is stored in the *constant data* section of your executable (which is loaded into memory when your process is started). Although `ptr` is a local variable, the compiler initialises it to point to the `"OK"` that is stored elsewhere. When you return `ptr` to the caller, the pointer still points to the same `"OK"`.

Comment: the C standard doesn't use the term "constant data section"

Comment: While that is true, it's more helpful than not using a name at all.

Comment: A string literal is a read-only object of type char-array with static storage duration. How a compiler implement this read-only property (as/in "constant data section","read-only data segment", or whatever...) is ever implementation-defined and therefore not primary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the location where the string `OK` is stored, then its stored in the **code section** of the memory and `ptr` is stored in the **stack**.

And the location of `OK` in code section is still accessible as its address is being returned by `func()`.

Also, the code section is **read only**. That is the reason why other answers suggested to make your function declaration as:

```
const char * func ()
```

That ensures the value pointed to, by returned address to be not modifiable. (pointer to a constant)

Answer (score 0):

`ptr`  holds the address of the `"OK"` data in the constant data section. That is the address being returned. Not the address of `ptr` So even if `ptr` ceases to exist, `"OK"` continues to  remain

Answer (score 0):

`char *ptr = "OK";` - This statement will allocate 4 bytes(if it is 32 bit machine) for the variable `ptr` and it will hold the address of the string literal `OK`. Now `ptr` is having a starting address(4bytes) of a string `OK` (which is actually 3 bytes including `\0`). This 3 bytes string`OK` will be in text segment, which is a read only data. You can't modify also. For example `ptr[0] = 'T'` is not possible in this case. String literals(3 bytes) in the text segment will exist through out the life time of process. But once the control comes out of the function `func`, then 4 bytes allocated for the variable `ptr` to hold address of the string literal will be freed. You can write your function `func` like below also

```
char* func()
{
    return "OK";
}
```

Change your function like below

```
char* func()
{
    char ptr[] = "OK";
    return ptr;
}
```

This time 3 bytes will be alloacted for the variable `ptr` to store the string locally. Scope of this is within the function only.

Answer (score 0):

ptr itself on stack is transient but where it points to is not. One circumstance is like in your func(), which string literal is stored in "constant data area", the other circumstance is data being allocated on the heap, i.e. through malloc(), therefore being global and would not be destroyed when the stack of function is gone.

```
char* func()
{
        char* ptr;
        ptr = (char*)malloc(100);
        strcpy(ptr, "OK");
        return ptr;
}
```