# Memory Leak Struct char C

Tags: c, memory, struct

I think I have some memory leak here.
Maybe someone can show me the right way how to handle leaks in situations like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct adresse {
    char *name;
    int nummer;
};

int main() {

    int size = 2;
    struct adresse *a = (struct adresse *) malloc(sizeof(struct adresse) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i].name = "Testname";
        a[i].nummer = 123;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s, %d\n", a[i].name, a[i].nummer);
    }

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak here?

Comment: Why do you think you have a memory leak? The only problem I see is that you didn't check for `malloc` returning `NULL`. Other than that, the code is looks OK.

Comment: @immibis maybe because of the char in the struct

Comment: You can't `free` "Testname" because it is a string literal. The `struct` member only contains a pointer.

Comment: @Pablo what do you mean with checking for NULL?

Comment: Excuse me for butting in, but robust code should check the the return value from all functions, where provided for your benefit. `NULL` here means there was no memory available.

Comment: @AmirKhan I mean `if(a == NULL) { // error handling }`. I know that is technically not an memory leak, but if `malloc` returns `NULL`, accessing it will cause a segfault. Other than that I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: I might recommend using `calloc` instead of `malloc`, and using `size_t` instead of `int` for things like your variable `size` and array indexes.

Comment: I would suggest allocating a memory segment for your char pointer as well.

Comment: @RannLifshitz Can you elaborate on this? Provided that `adresse::name` values won't be modified or require unique values there's no need to allocate any more memory.

Comment: What does `valgrind ./yourexename` tell you? (or similar memory use/error check for your OS)

Comment: @Dai : This is a matter of personal opinion and painful debugging in later phases of development - the code snippet used described a situation where a char pointer points to a string literal, in order to get around the need to allocate memory to a string and then use the allocated memory's pointer.
This can work, with certain limitations as seen here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267114/scope-of-string-literals

IMHO this is dangerous code writing which is bug prone. When writing in c++ I prefer to have my memory well managed and clearly defined and allocated.

Answer (score 3):

> **I think I have some memory leak here. Maybe someone can show me the right way how to handle leaks in situations like this.**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

If you allocate it, track it, and `free` it when it is no longer needed. If you didn't allocate it, you can't `free` it. If you have already freed it, you can't `free` it again.

> " if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined."

[C11 §7.22.3.3 The free function [p2] (n1570 draft)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2)

The only thing you allocate is `a`, you then later free `a` -- **you don't have a memory leak**.

**Example Memory Use/Error Check**

You can easily confirm whether you have a memory leak or not by using a memory usage/error checking program (such as `valgrind` on Linux -- there are similar programs for each OS). They are simple to use, just run your program through it:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/leak
==23745== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23745== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23745== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23745== Command: ./bin/leak
==23745==
Testname, 123
Testname, 123
==23745==
==23745== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23745==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23745==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==23745==
==23745== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==23745==
==23745== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23745== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

(**note**, depending on your OS and it's implementation of `valgrind`, it may show memory allocated by the system for your process still in use at program exit. Not all implementations of `valgrind` provide proper suppression files to mask all memory allocated by the OS for your process and not you. As long as you confirm that the memory you allocate has been freed -- you have done your job.)

As you can see from the above `valgrind` output, you have no errors and all memory allocated has been freed. (good job!)

Comment: Great answer to a strange question. Usually we get questions like "my code doesn't work" and then they post code that's leaking like crazy. This time is the other way round.

Comment: Yes, for some reason dynamically allocated memory, and its management seems like a stumbling block for those learning C. The books cover it, but a overwhelming majority (me included) after reading over it for the first time, it wasn't something I felt completely comfortable with. After making use of it a couple of times you see how simple it really is, but it usually isn't presented in a way to convey that understanding on first read. Probably because pointers and memory allocation are covered 4 chapters apart and without reference to the standard or memory checking programs.

Comment: Yes, in the beginning I also had my fair share of troubles with pointers and memory allocation. I didn't learn too much with books, but I practised a lot. At some point, you just get it.

Answer (score -1):

You should malloc the Testname string as well. It makes it a little more complicated to free everything because you'll need to free all the Testname strings first, and then free the overall struct memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct adresse {
  char *name;
  int nummer;
};

int main() {

    int size = 2;
    struct adresse *a = (struct adresse *) malloc(sizeof(struct adresse) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      char *str = "Testname";
      size_t len = strlen(str);
      a[i].name = malloc(len+1);
      memset(a[i].name, 0, len+1);
      memcpy(a[i].name, str, len);
      a[i].nummer = 123;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s, %d\n", a[i].name, a[i].nummer);
        free(a[i].name);
    }

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This makes the program more complicated for no reason. Also it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is true if he wishes to ultimately be able to modify the data that name points to.  It depends what his final use for this data will be.

Comment: @StephenDocy that's not necessarily true He could also set pointers of `char` arrays declared and initialized in `main`. You can modify them even without using `malloc`.

Comment: @Snohdo just because you see a `char*`, doesn't mean that you have to use `malloc`. In your code you could at least fix the first `malloc`, you shouldn't cast it and it's best practice to do `malloc(size * sizeof *a)`.